# HtmlDecode of html encoded space is not space

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Till now I was thinking `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;")` was a space. But the below code always returns false.

```
string text = "&nbsp;";

text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);

string space = " ";

if (String.Compare(space, text) == 0)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Same when I try with `Server.HtmlDecode()`

Why is it so?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks,
N

Comment: Apart from the non breaking space, `You should not use the Compare method to test for equality (that is, to explicitly look for a return value of 0 with no regard for whether one string is less than or greater than the other). Instead, to determine whether two strings are equal, use the StringEquals(String, String, StringComparison) method.` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz.aspx

Comment: @Habib or more simply, in most cases, just `==`.

Answer (score 17):

The HTML entity `&nbsp;` doesn't represent a space, it represents a non-breaking space.

The non-breaking space has character code 160:

```
string nbspace = "\u00A0";
```

---

Also, as Marc Gravell noticed, you have double encoded the code, so you would need to decode it twice to get the character:

```
string text = "&amp;nbsp;";
text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text));
```

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space for more information related to this.

Comment: "&amp;nbsp;" I added like that supposing this page will consider it as space when I submit the question. Never mind . I will try editing

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Ok now what I want is to return the HtmlDecode of '&nbsp;' as normal space. How should I do that? Any other way other than String.Replace ?

Comment: @user1481853: No, the non-breaking space is simply not a space, so if you want a space instead you have to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm cleaning the html like this:

```
  var text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html)
      .Replace("\u00A0", " ") // Replace non breaking space with space.
      .Replace("  ", " ") // Shrink multiple spaces into one space.
      .Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML of `&amp;nbsp;` doesn't mean **any** kind of space. It means, literally, the text `&nbsp;` - for example, if you were writing HTML that was talking about HTML, you may need to include the text `&nbsp;`, which you would do by writing the HTML `&amp;nbsp;`.

If you had:

```
string text = "&nbsp;";
```

then *that* would decode to a **non-breaking** space.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I faced the same issue some minutes ago.
I solved it in this way:

```
string text = "&nbsp;";
text = Server.HtmlDecode(text).Trim;
```

so now:
`text = ""` is true (the Trim at the end eliminates the space)